# Poisson Distribution and Recursion

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I have a discrete random variable $X$ with range natural numbers including $0$. It's given the probability mass function of $X$ fullfills this recursion equation:

$$f_X(x) = \frac3x f(x − 1),\ x \in\mathbb N. $$

Now the question is what kind of a distribution is this and I have the solution that it is a Poisson distribution with

$$f_X(x) = \frac{e^{-3}3^x}{x!},\ x\in\mathbb  N_0$$

I dont understand how? Can anyone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a first-order difference equation, for which the techniques of solution are well known.  If you multiply the equation through by $\ \frac{x!}{3^x}\ $, you get
$$
\frac{x!\,f_X(x)}{3^x}=\frac{(x-1)!\,f_X(x-1)}{3^{x-1}}\ ,
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\frac{x!\,f_X(x)}{3^x}-\frac{(x-1)!\,f_X(x-1)}{3^{x-1}}=0\ .
$$
Now summing this last equation from $\ x=1\ $ to $\ x=y\ $ gives
\begin{align}
0&=\sum_{x=1}^y\left(\frac{x!\,f_X(x)}{3^x}-\frac{(x-1)!\,f_X(x-1)}{3^{x-1}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{x=1}^y\frac{x!\,f_X(x)}{3^x}-\sum_{x=1}^y\frac{(x-1)!\,f_X(x-1)}{3^{x-1}}\\
&=\sum_{x=1}^y\frac{x!\,f_X(x)}{3^x}-\sum_{x=0}^{y-1}\frac{x!\,f_X(x)}{3^x}\\
&=\frac{y!\,f_X(y)}{3^y}-f_X(0)\  
\end{align}
from which we conclude that
$$
f_X(y)=\frac{3^y\,f_X(0)}{y!}\ .
$$
Since $\ f_X(y)\ $ is a probability mass function, its values must sum to $1$:
\begin{align}
1&=\sum_{y=0}^\infty f_X(y)\\
&=\sum_{y=0}^\infty\frac{3^y\,f_X(0)}{y!}\\
&=e^3f_X(0)\,
\end{align}
which gives $\ f_X(0)=e^{-3}\ $.

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't $f_X(y) = \frac{3^y f_X(0)}{y!}$ follow immediately from the given recursion (via induction)?

Comment: Yes, if you're given the answer, then you can simply prove it's correct by induction.  I took the OP to be asking how one could *find* the answer if you hadn't been given it.